# protocolとdelegateによる別View内の関数実行

Tags: swift, swift2

protocolとdelegateを利用して、他View内の関数を実行したいと考えています。

【やりたいこと】
`PlacePickerView`で都道府県を選択した時に、`NoTeamView`内の`TextField`と`Button`のラベルをその都道府県に変更したい。

【現状】
シミュレータは起動するが、`pickerview`を選択した際、
`print("tete\(placeValues[row])")`は効いているものの、
`print("this\(selectedValue)")`と`print("test")`が効かない。

NoTeamView.swift

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class NoTeamView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, PlacePickerViewDelegate {

    var noTeamPlaceEditButton : UIButton = UIButton()
    var noTeamPlaceTextField : UITextField = UITextField()

    var placePickerView = PlacePickerView()


    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        setupCustomView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        setupCustomView()
    }


    func setupCustomView() {
        noTeamPlaceTextField.placeholder = "活動地域"
        noTeamPlaceTextField.inputView = placePickerView
        self.addSubview(noTeamPlaceTextField)

        noTeamPlaceEditButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HiraginoSans-W6",size: CGFloat(12))
        noTeamPlaceEditButton.addTarget(self, action: "noTeamPushPlaceEditButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(noTeamPlaceEditButton)
    }

    func setSelectedPlace(selectedValue: String){
        print("this\(selectedValue)")
        noTeamPlaceEditButton.setTitle("▼ \(selectedValue)", forState: .Normal)
        noTeamPlaceTextField.text = "\(selectedValue)"
    }

    func test(){
        print("test")
    }
}
```

PlacePickerView.swift

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol PlacePickerViewDelegate {
    func setSelectedPlace(selectedValue: String)
    func test()
}

class PlacePickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    weak var passPlaceDelegate:PlacePickerViewDelegate?

    let placeValues = ["全国","北海道","青森","岩手","宮城","秋田","山形","福島","茨城","栃木","群馬","埼玉","千葉","東京","神奈川","新潟","富山","石川","福井","山梨","長野","岐阜","静岡","愛知","三重","滋賀","京都","大阪","兵庫","奈良","和歌山",
                       "鳥取","島根","岡山","広島","山口","徳島","香川","愛媛","高知","福岡","佐賀","長崎","熊本","大分","宮崎","鹿児島","沖縄"]

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code

        self.delegate = self
        var indexPlaceVale = placeValues.indexOf("北海道")
        self.selectRow(indexPlaceVale!, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }

    func pickerView(PickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("tete\(placeValues[row])")
        self.passPlaceDelegate?.setSelectedPlace(placeValues[row])
        self.passPlaceDelegate?.test()
    }
}
```

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。 ご教授いただいたコードで試したところ、うまく動きました。 

delegateをセットしないと、nilを返してしまうのですね。
今回はご教授いただき、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたが現在提示されているコードには`PlacePickerView`クラスのインスタンスである`placePickerView`の`passPlaceDelegate`をセットするコードがどこにも見当たりません。従って:

```
self.passPlaceDelegate?.setSelectedPlace(placeValues[row])
self.passPlaceDelegate?.test()
```

が実行される時には`self.passPlaceDelegate`は`nil`なのですから、`?.`で指定された`setSelectedPlace(placeValues[row])`も`test()`も呼び出されることはありません。

あなたのコードの書き方だと`setupCustomView()`の処理に1行付け加えるのが適当だと思います。

```
placePickerView.passPlaceDelegate = self
```